# Hide the Action Bar in the login screen fragment in android

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to hide action bar in android, and got this section of program, it hides initially but then it come from the top. what can be reason behind? and how to solve this?

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
               View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Comment: Add more details. Please and I would prefer Activity for Login Screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need in-depth about this post but you can try something like this

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.hide()
```

Comment: basically i am trying to work with MVVC. I have designed a login fragment and dashboard fragment. So in my dashboard i want to have action bar, but not in login form. as the action bar will contain the cart and notification. please let me know how can i elaborate more.

Comment: Then you can try the above code remember activity context will play an important role in this.

Comment: It worked for me, Thank You for the help. Thank you so much you saved me.

Comment: You should accept the answer that will help others to know about this.